# stop two javascript functions from running at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

got two jquery functions that run at the same time but i only want one of them to run at once

```js
$(".newspaper_nav_int").hide();
$("#hide_list").hide();

$(".newspaper_nav").hover( function() {
  hover();
})

$("#hide_list").click(function() {
  hide_list()
})


function hover() {
  $(".newspaper_nav_int").fadeIn(500)
  $("#hide_list").fadeIn(1500)
}
function hide_list() {
  $(".newspaper_nav_int").fadeOut(500)
  $("#hide_list").fadeOut(1500)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid these animations overlapping, you can use a flag to restrict animations when fading in/out.  Use a callback in `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`.   This will prevent these methods from animating simultaneously.

```
var animating = false;
function hover() {
  if(animating) return;
  animating = true;
  $(".newspaper_nav_int").fadeIn(500, () => { animating = false; })
  $("#hide_list").fadeIn(1500, () => { animating = false; })
}
function hide_list() {
  if(animating) return;
  animating = true;
  $(".newspaper_nav_int").fadeOut(500, () => { animating = false; });
  $("#hide_list").fadeOut(1500, () => { animating = false; });
}
```